# Finding Lifetime Incidence Based on Annual Incidence

Tags: probability, statistics

This question should be simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. The thing I can't wrap my head around most of all is how to calculate lifetime incidence among a whole population based on a certain amount per 1000 per year. Skip to the bold text if you want to give me a sufficient, hands-on explanation of this. I might even prefer an explanation of the bold text first so I can try the more complicated case-by-case situation myself.

There are about 21 million American males between the ages of 35 and 44. Approximately 3 per 1000 experience cardiovascular events each year (so 3 per 1000 per year).

Furthermore, there are about 22 million American males between the ages of 45-54. Their incidence rates of CVD lie at about 10 per 1000 per year.

There are about 17 million American males between the ages of 55-65, and the number of cardiovascular incidents is calculated to be about 21 per 1000 per year.

There are 18 million American males aged 65 and older. The incidence of their cardiovascular events lies at 65 per 1000 per year.

Given these numbers, what percentage of all American males will experience a cardiovascular event in their lifetime.

**Say that there are 60 million American males between the ages of 35 and 65. Approximately 11 per 1000 experience cardiovascular events each year, i.e., 11 per 1000 per year. Assume this is the only category that experiences CVD-events. Given these numbers, what percentage of *all* American males will experience cardiovascular events in their lifetime assuming that there are 150 million American males?**